# Nested "If-else" statements in CodeEffects rule

Tags: rule-engine, business-rules, nested-if, codeeffects

I am using CodeEffects rule editor for writing business rules in our application. I have many if-else conditions which are actually nested-if type rules. With no support of nested-if, I need to re-write all if conditions every time.

But I can't find any way to write rule as mentioned below.

- if (Condition1)

  - (

    - if (sub-condition1)( ....)
    - else if (....)
  - )
- else

  - (

    - ....
  - )

Answer (score 1):

The best way to substitute nested IFs is to use the same sub-conditions multiple times:

if condition1 and sub-condition1 then DoOneThing
else if sub-condition1 then DoAnotherThing
else DoSomethingElse

It's not perfect but it'll do.